# Ancova with multiple independent variables and 1 categorical variable

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am new to running Ancova in R. I am trying to see if my categorical variable (time) is significant in my dependent variable (Sales) while holding all other variables in my model constant.

```
aov(Sales ~ Price+Merch+ACV+Items+Category+Time, data = PintsT)
```

My question is how are you confident the `Pvalues` are relevant when holding the other variables constant? Does it automatically assume this using a type 3 analysis?

Also when would you use `*` instead of `+` in between the independent variables?